# Работа с директориями на Windows, c

Tags: c, windows, gcc

Планирую написать прогу для прогулки по директориям и поиска необходимых файлов, а затем действиями с этими файлами, но уперся в то, что на Винде некоторые (большинство, очевидно) линуксовских библиотек и функций либо отсутствуют вовсе (findnext, struct ffblk (?) в dir.h), либо определены немного уже (как в случае со struct dirent в dirent.h). Пользуюсь gcc. В попытке разобраться, как адоптироваться, впал в жесточайшую депрессию, которая вот-вот обернется установкой Линукса.
Вопрос(ы):
-как адаптировать приведенный ниже псевдокод (буду рад сслыкам в том числе)
 
-стоит ли, между прочим, переходить на Линукс (вопрос не основной, прошу не засорять тему ответами на него)`

```
void dirwaker(const char * dir){
    DIR * d = opendir(dir);
    if(!d) return;
    strcut dirent *ent;
    while((ent = readdir(d))!=NULL){
        if(ent->d_type==DT_DIR)
            dirwalker(dir "+" / + "+"ent->d_name); //"+" - условный плюс. Подразумевается склейка строк
        //танцуем
        if(ent->d_name == "я файл"){
            //беснуемся
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: [FindFirstFile, FindNextFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea)

Comment: @MBo благодарю, готов отметить как решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для поиска файлов Windows предоставляет функции [FindFirstFile, FindNextFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) и иже с ними